# Add 2 numbers together, one from a database result and the other from post array

Tags: mysql, post, pdo, sql-update, addition

I'm trying to add 2 numbers together. The first number is from the database say it's 150 it comes from the $sql1 and the second number comes from the form and is in the POST array say it's 25. Once the $sql2 is run the number in the database should be 175 but it's still 150, any ideas on what i'm missing/doing wrong?

```
$sql1 = "SELECT points FROM users WHERE userID = ?";
$qc1 = $pdo_conn->prepare($sql1);
$qc1->execute(array($_POST['userID']));
$result = $qc1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$points = $result + $_POST['addPoints'];

$sql2 = "UPDATE users SET points = ? WHERE userID = ?";
$qc2 = $pdo_conn->prepare($sql2);
$qc2->execute(array($points, $_POST['userID']));
```

Comment: Use `$result['points']` instead of `$result`

Comment: Like this: $points = $result['points'] + $_POST['addPoints']; ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code, the `$result` variable is going to return the response from the database as an array.  Thus, in order to get the number, you need to pass the field name from your `SELECT` statement.

Therefore,

`$points = $result + $_POST['addPoints'];`

should be:

`$points = $result['points'] + $_POST['addPoints'];`

Comment: added a echo $points under that line and it's still 25 and not 175

Comment: @jenstar Post a `var_dump($result)`

Comment: @jenstar np, if that is all, you can accept this as the answer.